# WSO2 Custom Mediator Set value for the Envelope

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

Deal All,

I'd create one custom mediator in my WSO2 ESB project at the OutSequence.

I would like to change the result in SOAP Envelope being send from the back end to the consumer. But with a little bit of adjustment to the data according to the result.

this is the SOAP Envelope

```
<soapenv:Bodyxmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<jsonObject>
    <serviceRequestID>12345</serviceRequestID>
    <statusCode>1</statusCode>
    <errorCode></errorCode>
    <errorDescription></errorDescription>
    <addressID>1.23456794E9</addressID>
    <source>consumer name</source>
    <requestId>910514</requestId>
</jsonObject>
```

I want to create a custom mediator to set the `Error Description` base on the `Error Code`.

For example,

if error code 1 = error description = one

if error code 2 = error description = two

if error code 3 = error description = three

This is my custom mediator code.

```
private void ResponseLogging(MessageContext mc) throws OMException{
    try {

        String errorCode = mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstChildWithName(new QName("errorCode")).getText();
        String errorDescription = null;

        if(errorCode.equals("1")) {
            errorDescription = "One";
        }else if(errorCode.equals("2")) {
            errorDescription = "Two";
        }else if(errorCode.equals("3")) {
            errorDescription = "Three";
        }

        mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstChildWithName(new QName("errorDescription")).setText(errorDescription);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Expected response,

```
<soapenv:Bodyxmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<jsonObject>
    <serviceRequestID>12345</serviceRequestID>
    <statusCode>1</statusCode>
    <errorCode>1</errorCode>
    <errorDescription>One</errorDescription>
    <addressID>1.23456794E9</addressID>
    <source>consumer name</source>
    <requestId>910514</requestId>
</jsonObject>
```

But now, I only get the `error description` as null.
kindly help. any advice would be great !

Thanks.

UPDATED !

Apparently, after set the value using the setText() method. The error description value change to `One` as expected in the log.

```
</statusCode><errorCode>1</errorCode><errorDescription>One</errorDescription>
```

But when the response is sent back to the client, it still null value.

```
{"serviceRequestID": "12345","statusCode": 1,"errorCode": "1", "errorDescription": "","addressID": 1.23456794E9,"source": "consumer name",   "requestId": "910514"}
```

Comment: Can you share the source of your sequence where you use this mediator?

Comment: @ophychius Hi there. do you mean my api.xml ? This is my api.xml

<api>
<inSequence>
<send><endpoint key="backendApi"/></send>
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
<sequence key="ResponseLoggingMediator"/>
<send/>
</outSequence>
</api>

Comment: @ophychius or you mean my sequence source code. here it is

<sequence name="ResponseLoggingMediator" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <class name="myipcs.csam.cdm.java.ResponseLoggingMediator"/>
</sequence>

Comment: @ameruddinjamil Why are you using a custom class mediator to do the transformation? Isn't it something you can do with the available mediators (enrich mediator or payload factory mediator)?

Comment: @AsankaAbeyweera Hi there. please teach me on how to do this ? so far that i know, the payload factory is to change the value of the content. I dont see any example where the value is change base on some other value (condition)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
private void ResponseLogging(MessageContext mc) throws OMException{
    try {

        String errorCode = mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstChildWithName(new QName("jsonObject")).getFirstChildWithName(new QName("errorCode")).getText();
        String errorDescription = null;

        if(errorCode.equals("1")) {
            errorDescription = "One";
        }else if(errorCode.equals("2")) {
            errorDescription = "Two";
        }else if(errorCode.equals("3")) {
            errorDescription = "Three";
        }

        mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstChildWithName(new QName("jsonObject")).getFirstChildWithName(new QName("errorDescription")).setText(errorDescription);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```